# How to fix or normalise MJML output for Mailchimp?

Tags: html, html-email, mjml

So, I'm working on developing a newsletter using the MJML framework (which is pretty great by the way), which I'd ideally like to distribute using our company Mailchimp account. I'm by no means married to using MC but our infrastructure uses their forms and for any number of other reasons we'd rather keep MC than switch.

The issue I'm beginning to run into is that the different email platforms seem to be processing the HTML output by the MJML in different ways. Putsmail seems to render closest to my expectations, but Mailchimp and inexplicably Mailjet each have their own separate rendering issues.

With Mailchimp, the main issue I have is that my hero section is rendered incorrectly in Outlook 365, with the image incorrectly placed. I am sure this is a Mailchimp issue as Outlook renders the Putsmail and Mailjet sections correctly. So, what I am wondering is what is making MC choke on my HTML and how can I compensate for this?

EDIT:

Trimmed HTML of the Relevant Section:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      #outlook a { padding:0; }
      body { margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text- 
size-adjust:100%; }
      table, td { border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
      img { border:0;height:auto;line-height:100%; outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
      p { display:block;margin:13px 0; }
    </style>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte mso 11]>
    <style type="text/css">
      .outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700);
    </style>
  <!--<![endif]-->



<style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
    .mj-column-per-66 { width:66.66666666666666% !important; max-width: 66.66666666666666%; }
.mj-column-per-33 { width:33.33333333333333% !important; max-width: 
33.33333333333333%; }
.mj-column-per-100 { width:100% !important; max-width: 100%; }
.mj-column-per-25 { width:25% !important; max-width: 25%; }
.mj-column-per-75 { width:75% !important; max-width: 75%; }
  }
</style>


    <style type="text/css">



@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  table.full-width-mobile { width: 100% !important; }
  td.full-width-mobile { width: auto !important; }
}

    </style>


  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#d7dde5;">


  <div
     style="background-color:#d7dde5;"
  >

  <table
     align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;"
  >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>


  <!--[if mso | IE]>
  <table
     align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
  >
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
  <![endif]-->


  <div  style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">

    <table
       align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;"
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td
             style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;"
          >
            <!--[if mso | IE]>
              <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>

        <td
           class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:399.99999999999994px;"
        >
      <![endif]-->

  <div
     class="mj-column-per-66 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"
  >

  <table
     border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%"
  >

        <tr>
          <td
             align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0px;word-break:break-word;"
          >

  <div
     style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;"
  ><span style="font-size: 11px">[[HEADLINE]]</span></div>

          </td>
        </tr>

  </table>

  </div>

      <!--[if mso | IE]>
        </td>

        <td
           class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:199.99999999999997px;"
        >
      <![endif]-->

  <div
     class="mj-column-per-33 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"
  >

  <table
     border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%"
  >

        <tr>
          <td
             align="right" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0px;word-break:break-word;"
          >

  <div
     style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:1;text-align:right;color:#000000;"
  ><span style="font-size: 11px"><a href="https://mjml.io" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">[[PERMALINK_LABEL]]</a></span></div>

          </td>
        </tr>

  </table>

  </div>

      <!--[if mso | IE]>
        </td>

    </tr>

              </table>
            <![endif]-->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>


  <!--[if mso | IE]>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->


        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table
     align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;"
  >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>


  <!--[if mso | IE]>
  <table
     align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
  >
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
  <![endif]-->


  <div  style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">

    <table
       align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;"
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td
             style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;"
          >
            <!--[if mso | IE]>
              <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>

        <td
           class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:199.99999999999997px;"
        >
      <![endif]-->

  <div
     class="mj-column-per-33 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"
  >

  <table
     border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%"
  >

        <tr>
          <td
             align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:0px;word-break:break-word;"
          >

  <table
     border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"
  >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td  style="width:125px;">

  <img
     alt="GreenTec Capital Logo" height="auto" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1oACJyNhnHMAqDTNlQCne1-Y4feLhCwZi" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px;" width="125"
  />

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

          </td>
        </tr>

  </table>

  </div>

      <!--[if mso | IE]>
        </td>

        <td
           class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:399.99999999999994px;"
        >
      <![endif]-->

  <div
     class="mj-column-per-66 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"
  >

  <table
     border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%"
  >

        <tr>
          <td
             align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:0px;word-break:break-word;"
          >

  <div
     style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#000000;"
  ><a href="#portfolio" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">Portfolio Updates</a><a href="#opportunities" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">Investment Opportunities</a></div></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table>
            <![endif]-->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>


  <!--[if mso | IE]>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->


        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!--[if mso | IE]>
    <table
       align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600"
    >
      <tr>
        <td  style="line-height:0;font-size:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <v:image
             style="border:0;height:300px;mso-position-horizontal:center;position:absolute;top:0;width:600px;z-index:-3;" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aQ2X43Qm0RqYJMGQfpOgUKXYGcIEe8pu" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
          />
  <![endif]-->
  <div
     style="margin:0 auto;max-width:600px;"
  >
    <table
       border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;"
    >
      <tr
         style="vertical-align:top;"
      >

      <td
         background="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aQ2X43Qm0RqYJMGQfpOgUKXYGcIEe8pu" style="background:#ffffff url(https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aQ2X43Qm0RqYJMGQfpOgUKXYGcIEe8pu) no-repeat center center / cover;background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;padding:0px;vertical-align:top;" height="300"
      >

  <!--[if mso | IE]>
    <table
       border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;" width="600"
    >
      <tr>
        <td  style="">
  <![endif]-->
  <div
     class="mj-hero-content" style="margin:0px auto;"
  >
    <table
       border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;margin:0px;"
    >
      <tr>
        <td  style="" >
          <table
             border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;margin:0px;"
          >

                <tr>
                  <td
                     align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:125px;padding-bottom:10px;word-break:break-word;"
                  >

  <div
     style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#ffffff;"
  ><span style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;">GreenTec Capital Partners</span><br/><br/>Investor Newsletter</div>

                  </td>
                </tr>

          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--[if mso | IE]>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <![endif]-->

      </td>

      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!--[if mso | IE]>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<![endif]-->

  <table
     align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;"
  >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>


  <!--[if mso | IE]>
  <table
     align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
  >
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
  <![endif]-->


  <div  style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">

    <table
       align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;"
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td
             style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;"
          >
            <!--[if mso | IE]>
              <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>

        <td
           class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
        >
      <![endif]-->
```

Garbled Mailchimp HTML for the Same Section:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head><title></title><!--[if !mso]><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
        &lt;!--
        <![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!--[if mso]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG /><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]--><!--[if lte mso 11]><style>.outlook-group-fix {
          width:100% !important;
          }
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !mso]>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        &lt;!--
        <style>
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
      <style type="text/css">
            #outlook a{
                padding:0;}
            body{margin:0;
                padding:0;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
                -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
            }table,td{
                border-collapse:collapse;
                mso-table-lspace:0;
                mso-table-rspace:0;
            }img{border:0;
                height:auto;
                line-height:100%;
                outline:none;
                text-decoration:none;
                -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
            }p{display:block;
                margin:13px 0;
            }#outlook a{padding:0;
            }body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
                -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
            }table,td{
                border-collapse:collapse;
                mso-table-lspace:0;
                mso-table-rspace:0;
            }img{
                border:0;
                height:auto;
                line-height:100%;
                outline:none;
                text-decoration:none;
                -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
            }p{display:block;margin:13px 0;
            }@media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-66{width:66.666666666667% !important;
                max-width:66.666666666667%;
            }}  @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-33{
                width:33.333333333333% !important;
                max-width:33.333333333333%;
            }}  @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-100{
                width:100% !important;
                max-width:100%;
            }}  @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-25{
                width:25% !important;
                max-width:25%;}
    }   @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-75{
                width:75% !important;
                max-width:75%;
            }}      #outlook a{
                padding:0;
            }
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
                -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
            }table,td{
                border-collapse:collapse;
                mso-table-lspace:0;
                mso-table-rspace:0;
            }img{
                border:0;
                height:auto;
                line-height:100%;
                outline:none;
                text-decoration:none;
                -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
            p{display:block;
                margin:13px 0;}
        @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-66{
                width:66.666666666667% !important;
                max-width:66.666666666667%;
            }}  @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-33{
                width:33.333333333333% !important;
                max-width:33.333333333333%;
            }}  @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-100{
                width:100% !important;
                max-width:100%;
            }}  @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-25{
                width:25% !important;
                max-width:25%;
            }}  @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mj-column-per-75{
                width:75% !important;
                max-width:75%;
            }}  @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
            table.full-width-mobile{
                width:100% !important;
            }}  @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
            td.full-width-mobile{
                width:auto !important;
            }}</style></head>
      <body style="background-color: #d7dde5;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><div style="background-color:#d7dde5;">    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tbody><tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;">
<!--[if mso | IE]><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;" width="600"><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
                        <![endif]-->
                  <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">

                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="direction: ltr;font-size: 0px;padding: 20px 0;text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top;width:399.99999999999994px;"><![endif]--><div class="mj-column-per-66 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align: top;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;" width="100%"><tr><td align="left" style="font-size: 0px;padding: 10px 25px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;"><span style="font-size: 11px">[[HEADLINE]]</span>
</div></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso | IE]></td><td style="vertical-align:top;width:199.99999999999997px;"><![endif]--><div class="mj-column-per-33 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">

                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align: top;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="right" style="font-size: 0px;padding: 10px 25px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"> <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:1;text-align:right;color:#000000;"><span style="font-size: 11px"><a href="https://mjml.io" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit;">[[PERMALINK_LABEL]]</a></span>
                                </div>

                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </div>

                        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      </td>

                    </tr>

                  </table>
                  <![endif]-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>


              <!--[if mso | IE]>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->


            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background: #ffffff;background-color: #ffffff;width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;">


              <!--[if mso | IE]>
              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;" width="600">
                <tr>
                  <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]--> <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tbody><tr><td style="direction: ltr;font-size: 0px;padding: 20px 0;text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top;width:199.99999999999997px;"><![endif]--><div class="mj-column-per-33 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align: top;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;" width="100%"><tr><td align="center" style="font-size: 0px;padding: 10px 25px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0px;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tbody><tr><td style="width: 125px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><img alt="GreenTec Capital Logo" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1oACJyNhnHMAqDTNlQCne1-Y4feLhCwZi" style="border: 0;display: block;outline: none;text-decoration: none;height: auto;width: 100%;font-size: 13px;line-height: 100%;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="125"></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
</tr></table></div><!--[if mso | IE]></td><td style="vertical-align:top;width:399.99999999999994px;"><![endif]--><div class="mj-column-per-66 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align: top;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;" width="100%"><tr><td align="center" style="font-size: 0px;padding: 10px 25px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#000000;"><a href="#portfolio" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit;">Portfolio Updates</a><a href="#opportunities" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit;">Investment Opportunities</a></div></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table>
                  <![endif]--></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
              <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--[if mso | IE]>
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600">
        <tr>
          <td style="line-height:0;font-size:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
            <v:image style="border:0;height:300px;mso-position-horizontal:center;position:absolute;top:0;width:600px;z-index:;" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aQ2X43Qm0RqYJMGQfpOgUKXYGcIEe8pu" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" />
            <![endif]-->
      <div style="margin:0 auto;max-width:600px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;">
          <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
            <td background="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aQ2X43Qm0RqYJMGQfpOgUKXYGcIEe8pu" style="background: #ffffff url('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aQ2X43Qm0RqYJMGQfpOgUKXYGcIEe8pu') no-repeat center;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;" height="300">

              <!--[if mso | IE]>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;" width="600"><tr><td><![endif]--><div class="mj-hero-content" style="margin:0px auto;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;margin: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;margin: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tr><td align="center" style="font-size: 0px;padding: 10px 25px;padding-top: 125px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;"><div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#ffffff;"><span style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;">GreenTec Capital Partners</span><br><br>Investor Newsletter</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr> </table><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Sounds like an odd issue. Mailchimp definitely alters the HTML, but it shouldn't really break anything.
It may actually be best to provide both your original MJML output as well as the result of Mailchimps alterations.

That way we can compare and see what Mailchimp is changing compared to your original output.

Comment: Is there a good way to share the code? the code pushes the post body over the character limit?

Comment: I had to trim a lof of the whitespace to paste the relevant code section.

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately that won't work as we'll need to see the entire code with closing tags. If you're having issues with character limits, I would suggest clicking on the icon in the text editor that looks like a piece of paper with the opening and closing tags (<>). That doesn't seem to be limiting me. Alternatively you could paste into a service such as Codepen.io, jsfiddle.net or codesandbox.io and then posting a direct link on here.